# Permutation group and their subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I need to verify these two statements.

1. Every finite group is a subgroup of $A_n$ for some $n\geq 1$.
2. Every finite group is a quotient of $A_n$ for some $n\geq 1$.

I think first one is false since an odd permutation in $S_n$ should remain odd in every other $S_m$ for $m\geq n$.  I am not sure if I proceed right.

Answer (score 3):

You should know something about the [normal subgroups (i.e. the possible kernels of homomorphisms) of $A_{n}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group#Basic_properties), for $n \ge 5$.

As to the first question, do you know that [every finite group is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $S_{n}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley's_theorem)? Because then there is a (rather straightforward) way of showing that [$S_{n}$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A_{n+2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Relation_with_alternating_group).